# In a service, why can you make toast in onDestroy() but not onHandleIntent()?

Tags: android

It's sort of academic but how come the following displays toast:

```
public class MyService extends IntentService
{

public PdfRotateService() {
    super("MyService");
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
{
    doSomeThings();

}
@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(this, text, duration).show();
}


}
```

,but putting Toast.makeText() in onHandleIntent() instead doesn't display Toast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the documentation to understand how each method works. According to the documentation of [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) `onHandleIntent` runs on a worker thread that that runs independently from other application logic. For `Toast` to work, it has to be implemented in the main UI thread